# How can I display a backslash in a browser using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

as mentioned below, I have some code in my jsp inside a script tag .

I am getting this: `444444444666666666666666666\888888888888`

but I want this: `444444444\666666666666666666\\888888888888`
(The backslash should be escaped)

So how can i avoid this and display the text as it is?  I have tried different ways to replace the backslash("\") but I have been unsuccessful.

```
 <script>
      var mytxt ="444444444\666666666666666666\\888888888888";
  document.write(mytxt);   
 </script>

  Actual O/P in browser : 444444444666666666666666666\888888888888
  Expected O/P in browser : 444444444\666666666666666666\\888888888888
```

Comment: I used mytxt = mytxt.replace('\\',"\\\\"); to replace the backslash("\") but no change in output

Answer (score 8):

Escape each backslash with another backslash:

```
444444444\\666666666666666666\\\\888888888888
```

When you want to represent a single `\`, use `\\`.

Comment: I don't have control on the text which is coming to display. and I used     mytxt = mytxt.replace('\\',"\\\\"); to replace  backslash but no difference in O/P

Comment: The problem here is that the string has already "forgotten" about the extra slashes before you're able to replace them.  How are you generating the strings? I assume it's not static, as you could just fix it manually...

Comment: @Satya: The `'\'` character isn't what you think it is. It is used to denote special characters, like `\n` and `\r`. `\n` is a *single* character (you can't replace the `'\'`, because it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 3):

Replace backslash `"\"` with `"\\"`

Answer (score 1):

You should escape backslash character. `\\` is one backslash `\\\\` are two.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out the backslashes are an escape sign. If you want to print out your backslashes then you have to print it twice.

Trying a simple replace probably won't work, because its a special character.